# Java byte array to double conversion

Tags: java, arrays, bit-manipulation, decode

I'm trying to convert an array of bytes to a double value.

```
private static double bytesToDouble(byte[] array) {
    long l=bytesToLong(array[7],array[6],array[5],array[4],array[3],array[2],array[1],array[0]);
    return Double.longBitsToDouble(l);
}

    private static long bytesToLong(byte b7,byte b6,byte b5,byte b4,byte b3,byte b2,byte b1,byte b0){
  //se il byte è signed viene trasf. in unsigned
  return (b0<0 ? b0+256L : b0)        |
         ((b1<0 ? b1+256L : b1) << 8) |
         ((b2<0 ? b2+256L : b2) << 16)|
         ((b3<0 ? b3+256L : b3) << 24)|
         ((b4<0 ? b4+256L : b4) << 32)|
         ((b5<0 ? b5+256L : b5) << 40)|
         ((b6<0 ? b6+256L : b6) << 48)|
         ((b7<0 ? b7+256L : b7) << 56);
}
```

Anyway, something seems not to work properly. I know the input array is

0
0
0
0
0
0
12
-124

And the expected value is 641.5, but I get another value (-3.591469701136079E-289).

I know that the code generating the byte sequence works well because it is being used in production environment from a long time.

How can I manipulate the bytes array (or the bytes themselves) to get the expected value?

Regards

Comment: Why negatives? I actually have a problem, I documented it, please explain instead of just downvote...

Comment: Negative maybe because of the fact that this probably is asked often. About the error: my guess it is the byte order. For the nice answer below: you can insert `.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)` to change the default order.

Comment: I tried also to reverse the array, still not getting the expected result. I know the easiest answer is "the input is wrong, not the output", but everything else in my decoder is working properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).putDouble(641.5);
    System.out.println("Result: " + Arrays.toString(bytes));
    // Result: [64, -124, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

So the byte order is little endian (Windows Intel), and especially one byte value went missing, one `read()` too much; my guess a silly mistake like:

```
while (read() != -1) {
    ... read array
```

The correct data can be converted by:

```
double val = ByteBuffer.wrap(array).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getDouble();
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check the full binary string containing data.

Comment: I confirm, I had to increment by 1 the reading index in the byte array :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using java.nio.ByteBuffer (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)

For example,

```
double val = ByteBuffer.wrap(array).getDouble(0);
```

Comment: And with `.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)`?

Comment: If you know the expected end-result, can you use ByteBuffer#putDouble on the byte[8] array and examine the byte values.

Java stores float / double as per floating-point standard derived from IEEE 754

Ref : http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/